# Difference between prop and trigger

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Is there a difference between:

```
$('.mycheckbox').prop('checked',true);
```

and

```
$('.mycheckbox').trigger('click');
```

Both of the statements, *check* the checkbox. But is there anything different that happens?

Comment: `$('.mycheckbox').trigger('click');` will additionally trigger any event handlers attached for the click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are completely different

Prop is for properties while trigger is for events.

when you say

```
$('.mycheckbox').prop('checked',true);
```

the element which matches the selector ".mycheckbox" is obtained and a property checked is set to true.

prop deals with HTML properties

while coming to trigger it deals with events

```
$('.mycheckbox').trigger('click');
```

the click event corresponding to the element that matches to the selector ".mycheckbox" is triggered.

when a click event happens its listeners are executed.

If you write a custom event listener they will be called after the event is triggered

Answer (score 0):

`prop` will not trigger change event, and you can pass boolean to check or uncheck

```
$('.mycheckbox').prop('checked',true);
```

where as `trigger click` does trigger events and alternate check uncheck

```
$('.mycheckbox').trigger('click');
```

see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsw8jzLu/)